# ListFragment Support Library GetSupportFragmentManager undefined

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a list Fragment (importing the v4 support library, build target is 2.3.3 api 11)
and the following problem in my code that was working fine when the target was 3.0 and I didn't use the library.

```
Fragment frag1 = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.contentframe, frag1);
ft.commit();
```

Now I'm getting the compile error that

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from ExampleFragment to Fragment"
```

and it tells me to change the "Fragment" to ExampleFragment (e.g.)

```
ExamplesFragment frag1 = new ExamplesFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.contentframe, frag1);
ft.commit();
```

Then I have a problem that the ft.replace command has an error:

```
The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment_PVAnn)
```

and it tells me to change the ExamplesFragment in the first line back to just Fragment and so the circle goes round and around

Comment: is ExamplesFragment extending Fragmentclass ? please provide ExamplesFragment code .........

Comment: Fragment in 3.0 and Fragment in support lib is not the same. So if you use the fragment manager from the support lib, and the Fragment from 3.0, or the other way round, you get this error. Make sure you use either support lib or 3.0/4.0 fragments consistently.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

If that is still giving you problems, then makre sure that your `Activity extends FragmentActivity`.

If that is still giving you problems,

1. Delete *all* of your imports,
2. Re-import with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and
3. On every name clash, make sure you import from `support.v4.*`, *not* `android.*`.

Comment: just another problem now. I tried launching it in a 2.3.3. emulator and it gave me an error for the main.xml file the error is "error inflating class fragment" it is at the line where my content frame layout is that i referenced above as contentframe

Comment: You'll have to be more clear... I don't really understand the error. You might want to add your code to a new StackOverflow post or something, it'll get more attention that way. Link me to the new post if you make it and I can help there. It's too difficult resolving issues like these in comments...

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that when you extend `Fragment` that you are extending the `Fragment` that is in the `v4` package space.  Check your imports for `Fragment`, `FragmentActivity`, etc, and if you see them imported WITHOUT .v4 in the package name, then it is wrong.

Also, if you set the android library for the project to be 2.3 and not 4.0.x then you'll quickly see if you are using the incorrect classes, because you'll get compile errors, which can be fixed by using the v4 classes from the android support jar (which hopefully you've included in your project as well)

Comment: a) i have included the support jar
b) I extend a ListFragment because i have a List displayed in this fragment

Comment: Is your activity also extending FragmentActivity?