# Passing results (serializable class) from DialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, serialization

I have main activity which contains fragments. One of the fragment is calling dialogFragment for new item entry. This new item is specified by Serializable class.
Just to be more specific:
item.java

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
private String mTitle;
private String mDescription;
private Boolean mTrue;


//getters and setters

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}
public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}
public void setDescription(String mDescription) {
    this.mDescription = mDescription;
}
public Boolean isTrue() {
    return mTrue;
}
public void setTrue(Boolean mTrue) {
    this.mTrue = mTrue;
}
}
```

DialogNewItem

```
public class DialogNewItem extends DialogFragment {


//filters state holder
Boolean isTrue = false;
//filters state end

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_item, null);

    final EditText editTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    final EditText editDescription = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editDescription)

    //filter icons
    final ImageView ivIsTrue = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.filterTrue);
    //filter icons end

    //onClickListener for filter icons
    ivIsTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (isTrue == false) {
                ivIsTrue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_white);
                ivIsTrue.setImageResource(R.drawable.true_white);
                isTrue = true;
            } else {
                ivIsTrue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_green);
                ivIsTrue.setImageResource(R.drawable.true_green);
                isTrue = false;
            }
        }
    });


    Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);


    builder.setView(dialogView);

    //cancel button
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    //give button
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //new item
            final Item newItem = new Item();

            //Set its variables to match the users entries on the form
            newItem.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());
            newItem.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
            newItem.setTrue(isTrue);



            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Now, I want to pass newItem from DialogNewItem (btnOK) to a listView Fragment. In other words I want to make a listView Fragment which will contain all the new items created in DialogNewItem. 
I was trying different methods (set/getFragment, ArrayList, different interfaces, etc) but some how non of it works. I have no problem with passing newItem to listView in an activity:

```
//get the reference to dashboard
Dashboard callingActivity = (Dashboard) getActivity();
//pass new item back to dashboard
callingActivity.createNewItem(newItem);
```

and then dashboard activity:

```
 public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

private ItemAdapter mItemAdapter;

public void createNewItem(Item n) {
    mItemAdapter.addItem(n);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    mItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter();
    ListView listItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listItem.setAdapter(mItemAdapter);
}

//handle clicks on listView
listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int whichItem, long id ){
        //creating temporary item which is reference to the clicked item
        Item tempItem = mItemAdapter.getItem(whichItem);
        //new dialog window
        DialogShowItem dialog = new DialogShowItem();
        //send reference to the item to be shown
        dialog.sendItemSelected(tempItem);
        //show the dialog window with the item
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"");
    }
});

@Override
public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    //has been inflated already
    if (view==null){
        //creating layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //instantiate view by inflating inflater (listItem layout)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup, false);
    }

    Item tempItem = itemList.get(whichItem);

    //grabbing the refrence to all variables
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

    ImageView ivTrue = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSmTrue);


    //setting text variables
    txtTitle.setText(tempItem.getTitle());
    txtDescription.setText(tempItem.getDescription());

    //hide not relevant images
    if (!tempItem.isTrue()){
        ivTrue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {ivTrue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    //category with different image src


    return view;
}
```

and everything works perfectly, but when I want to do the same with Fragment instead of Activity, somehow I cannot make it work.
I would appreciate any help. Thanx

Fragment (with listview):
    public class ListItems extends ListFragment {

```
private ItemAdapter mItemAdapter;

public void createNewItem(Item i) {
    mItemAdapter.addItem(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstatceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, container, false);

    //Item adapter
    mItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter();
    final ListView listItems = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listItems.setAdapter(mItemAdapter);


    //floating give button
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogNewItem dialog = new DialogNewItem();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
        }
    });

    //handle clicks on itemList
    listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int whichItem, long id) {
            Item tempItem = mItemAdapter.getItem(whichItem);
            DialogShowItem dialog = new DialogShowItem();
            dialog.sendItemSelected(tempItem);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mItemAdapter.saveItems();
}

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    private JSONSerializer mSerializer;

    public ItemAdapter() {
        mSerializer = new JSONSerializer("myProject.json", getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        try {
            itemList = mSerializer.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
            Log.e("Error loading items: ", "", e);
        }
    }

    public void saveItems() {
        try {
            mSerializer.save(itemList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error saving items: ", "", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int whichItem) {
        return itemList.get(whichItem);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int whichItem) {
        return whichItem;
    }

    public void addItem(Item n) {
        itemList.add(n);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);
        }

        Item tempItem = itemList.get(whichItem);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

        ImageView ivTrue = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSmTrue);

        //setting text variables
        txtTitle.setText(tempItem.getTitle());
        txtDescription.setText(tempItem.getDescription());

        //hide  irrelevant images
        if (!tempItem.isTrue()){
            ivTrue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {ivTrue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

        return view;
    }

}
}
```

It's a drawer activity so I'm showing it after drawer item click:

```
private void switchFragment(int position) {
Fragment fragment = null;
    String fragmentID = "";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragmentID = "LISTITEMS";
            fragment = new ListItems();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentID = "PROFILE";
            fragment = new Profile();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment, fragmentID).commit();
    //close the drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mNavDrawerList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a public method in ListItems fragment class in which you receive an Item class object and add it in adapter. And then inside your DialogNewItem Fragment, On OK Button click, you can search the ListItems using SupportFragmentManager by using its tag and call the public method you wrote.

The following code might help you.

DialogNewItem class

```
btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //new item
            final Item newItem = new Item();

            //Set its variables to match the users entries on the form
            newItem.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());
            newItem.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
            newItem.setTrue(isTrue);

            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            ListItems fragment = (ListItems)manager.findFragmentByTag("LISTITEMS");

            if(fragment != null){
               fragment.createNewItem(newItem);
            }            

            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

In your ListItems fragment the following code will depict an ItemAdapter as the data member of the ListViewFragment class and below that is the method you can call to add the item in the adapter.

```
private ItemAdapter mItemAdapter;

public void createNewItem(Item n) {
    mItemAdapter.addItem(n);
}
```

Comment: Thankx, but would ListViewFragment look like?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get what u asked. Did u able to solve the issue ?

Comment: sorry, I was just wondering how would this public method and adapter look like in ListViewFragment?

Comment: Can u tell me where exactly are u stuck so I can help you out there.

Comment: thanx! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Sure. I will be waiting for an upvote and answer acceptance I hope

Comment: ok, so I was try to use your code but I am receiving: Cannot resolve symbol SupportFragmentManager, same story with ListViewFragment, also I am curious why you used fragment.addItem instead of fragment.createNewItem? and final question how do I add tag to the fragment?

Comment: Please post the code you are using in Fragment. You haven't posted the ListView fragment code in question as well.

Comment: I have edited the code I wrote in my answer according to fragment. 
Now you still will have problem like setting your tag. It can be done from the place where you are initializing the fragment. It can be either in xml code or in your java code where you wrote fragmentTransaction.

Comment: actually I already figured out the same way you did it but I am still getting " Cannot resolve symbol SupportFragmentManager" and "Cannot resolve method on findFragmentByTag".

Comment: yes. I also set up fragment tag (I think).
    private void switchFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String fragmentID = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentID = "LISTITEMS";
                fragment = new ListItems();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Tag", "LISTITEMS");
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                break;

Comment: Please use 
public class Dashboard extends FragmentActivity in your activity because this method is only available in FragmentActivity.

Comment: Tag is not put that way. It is set in fragmentTransaction or in xml if you are using fragment through xml

Comment: wait, I'm lost now. The problem I have is in DialogNewItem (DialogFragment) so why should I change extension in my MainActivity (Dashboard)?

Comment: Its because FragmentActivity provides getSupportFragmentManager() method which in turn provides findFragmentById method to search for the fragment whose function 'createNewItem' you want to call to add the item in your ListItems Fragment. See all the things are pretty connected to each other.

Comment: ok so I did this "public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity" and I am still receiving " Cannot resolve symbol SupportFragmentManager" and "Cannot resolve method on findFragmentByTag" in DialogNewItem, also because I've change AppCompaActivity now I have problem with set/getSupportActionBar for the mainActivity Drawer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208335/listfragment-support-library-getsupportfragmentmanager-undefined

Look at its answer. That will help you in resolving this issue. Because there are alot of problems in conversion between AppCompatActivity to FragmentActivity. But you have to do it for the work you are needing in this question

Comment: ok, after changing from appcompa to fragmentactivity it still gives me the 2 same errors in dialogNewItem?!  " Cannot resolve symbol SupportFragmentManager" and "Cannot resolve method on findFragmentByTag"

Comment: I have edited the answer. FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); Try this. I thought SupportFragmentManager was a class but it is actually FragmentManager.

Comment: Ok, it work but with FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager(). Can you help me with setting up tag? also I don't know why but the application crashes (Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class)

Comment: ok, I fixed the R.id.list problem The last thing I need is how to set up the fragment TAG

Comment: Please tell me where you are showing fragment on the activity. FragmentTransaction is used there. We have to set tag there

Comment: I've edited my question. You can find it at the end of it.

Comment: Basically what you are setting as fragmentID, it is actually Fragment TAG, You can search the fragment by the same tag in the DialogNewItem fragment after getting fragment Manager. I have edited the answer. Please check now

Comment: that's what I thought before, but the app is crushing and after cklicking OK btn in DialogNewItem I'm getting "'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" error. This TextView is for the title and it's the first one to be passed from DialogNewItem to the fragment. So it looks like it's not working

Comment: Can u please put breakpoints on the line where you are getting FragmentManager to see that the values are setting correctly in Item Object or not

Comment: you mean just beforeFragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();ListItems fragment = (ListItems)manager.findFragmentByTag("LISTITEMS");
in DialogNewItem?

Comment: I am telling you we are close its just some small thing missed

Comment: ok, I've checked it. The values are set correctly, so it's still the same problem: passing newItem from DialogNewItem to listItems Fragment

Comment: Now check if you are receiving the fragment in fragment object or not ?

Comment: Not there. After findFragmentById function in DialogNewItem

Comment: yes, fragment = ListItems{5673fe6 #0 id=0x7f0d006b LISTITEMS}

Comment: I can help you via teamviewer if you want. I will know exactly where the problem is by debugging. What do u say ?

Comment: How about after 1.5 hrs ?